# replacing 2 different words with each other

Tags: find-and-replace

I want to replace 2 different text sentences with each other using only `Find and Replace` which you find amongst the most common word processing packages. For example let say I want to replace:

> Amharic - English - Japanese

to

> English - Amharic - Japanese

How can this be done?

Comment: More information is needed before anyone could possibly help you. What program are you using? What kind of file holds the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you ahve 2 options (without using Regex or similar).

Find it by the entire string - type in `Amharic - English - Japanese`
In the replace box, type in `English - Amharic - Japanese`

---

Or, if the format you've shown isn't constant, just do a direct replace with

Replace `Amharic` with `ThisWillBeEnglish-ThisIsAnUglyHackButItWorksAndIsAUniqueString`

Now, replace `English` with `Amharic`

Now, replace `ThisWillBeEnglish-ThisIsAnUglyHackButItWorksAndIsAUniqueString` with `English`

Comment: Thanks. I used the second menthod. I had to think of that!

Comment: Yes, it's a hack but, it works very well. I do suggest you save it before doing this though, just incase the string isn't unique  :)